# Swift - Dismiss ViewController Going Too Far Back

Tags: ios, swift4

When I click on cancel button in a modal pop-up `ViewController`, for some reason it goes to the very beginning of the `navigation` stack, instead of back to thew `viewController` that called it. Am I doing something wrong?

**Root of the stack, calling ViewControllerA:**

```
class RootViewController {
    let viewController = ViewControllerA(contact: selectedContact)
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}
```

**ViewControllerA / Calling the modal:**

```
let viewController = ViewControllerB()
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**ViewControllerB / Dismissing the modal:**

```
@objc func cancelButtonPressed() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: show me your navigation stack and in which VC your calling cancelButtonPressed function?

Comment: because you call to your rootviewcontroller. and i think you set your rootviewcontroller to first vc

Comment: @Venkadesh updated the post to include the view controllers

Comment: @RB1509 i think the rootViewController is just getting set as the newly initialized instance of ViewControllerB right?

Comment: @user3628240 if u call cancelButtonPressed() in ViewControllerB, it should dismiss ViewControllerB and display the ViewControllerA. Is it not happening?

Comment: @Venkadesh it dismissed ViewControllerB and displays A for a brief second, then ends up on the root view controller

Comment: @user3628240 : Show us what you have in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear of ViewController A. " displays A for a brief second" clearly states that your ViewController A gets dismissed after it comes to foreground

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Does dismiss automatically take you back to the root view controller? I don't want to go to the root view controller, but rather ViewControllerA, aka the one right after root view controller